# How to find the Input and Output Tensors for converting a .PB file (Faster RCNN Model) to a TFlite file?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I built an object detection model using Faster RCNN and able to generate the Frozen_Graph.pb file. Now I am trying to convert the .pb file to TFlite file for using it on Android. But I am facing issues while conversion. As it requires Input tensor and Output sensor for conversion.

I am not able to figure out the correct input and output arrays to be passed. Even If I pass the input tensor as `Image_tensor` it throws an error stating

```
 ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'image_tensor:0' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]
```

Below is the code that I am using for the conversion:

```
graph_def_file = "/models/mobilenet_thin_model.pb"
input_arrays = ["image_tensor"]
output_arrays = ["Softmax"]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(graph_def_file,input_arrays, output_arrays)

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("/models/converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the graph and parse it. Then print each node.

```
import tensorflow as tf
Graph = tf.GraphDef()   
File = open("Model.pb","rb")
Graph.ParseFromString(File.read())

for Layer in Graph.node:
    print(Layer.name)
```

Or get the last one directly

```
print(Graph.node[-1].name)
```

Btw. how did you implement TensorFlow in your Application? You don´t need the names when you use `import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter`. You only have to call `run` with your input and your output buffer.

An example from me, based on the TensorFlow example implementation:

```
private ByteBuffer _mInput;
private float[][] _mOutput;

Interpreter.Options _mTfliteOptions = new Interpreter.Options();
_mTfliteOptions.setNumThreads(1);
_mTfliteOptions.setUseNNAPI(true);

_mInput = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 1 * Width * Height * Channels);
_mInput.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

_mOutput = new float[1][_mClassLabels.size()];

_mTfLite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile(getActivity().getAssets(),"Model.tflite"), _mTfliteOptions);
_mTfLite.run(_mInput, _mOutput);

private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager Manager, String Path) throws IOException
{
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = Manager.openFd(Path);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kampi thanks for ur help. I am using python in windows for implementation. Now I am able to get the output tensor but if I feed in the input tensor as  "image_tensor" it throws the same error stating:                                                                                              
"invalid shape '{1}'.".format(_tensor_name(tensor), shape_list))

ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'image_tensor' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'.

Comment: Hi @Kampi now I am able to get the input and output tensor names and I am also able to run the tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph() function on those. But Now I am facing the below issue: "TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))

ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.

Comment: Please check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53751925/issues-when-converting-tensorflow-keras-model-to-tensorflow-lite-model) may help you.

Comment: Tried using TF-nightly but still getting the same error

Comment: Yes, I have some issues too with converting a `.pb` file into `.tflite`.
Do you have the model as Keras model? You can convert Keras to TFLite directly.